# Monte Carlo Methods

Tags: self-study, monte-carlo, random-generation, rejection-sampling

_I've tried using `sqrt p(1-p)/n` to get the standard error and then calculate the t test but for all parts I get a very large number of t so this means `p<0.05` and I reject so in the case of this question I reject all, can anyone let me know if I am doing it right?

--> my answer for part a for example   `sqrt 0.052(1-0.052)/1000` so   `standard error = 0.00702`   using    `t=0.052-0.05-0/(sqrt (0.00702squared/1000))`   in this case  `t=9.0079`  which gives a very small p-value so  `p<0.05`.

Imagine you have developed two random number generators to generate standard normal random variables. You perform a Monte Carlo test with both and estimate whether samples of `n = 1000` have a mean of `0`. You run `1000` replications and estimate `5%` rejection frequencies, and get the following:
_generator A `0.052`
_generator B `0.058`

(a) Test whether generator A’s rejection frequency is = `0.05`.

(b) Test whether generator B’s rejection frequency is = `0.05`.

-- After running `10,000` Monte Carlo simulations, you get the same rejection frequencies.

(d) Test whether generator A’s rejection frequency is = `0.05`.

(e) Test whether generator B’s rejection frequency is = `0.05`.

(f) Which generator should you use? Why?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Please show your working, not just a vague description of it

Comment: @Glen_b Here is my working for part a posted above  for 10000 monte carlo simulations I just replaced the 1000 with 10000

Comment: It's very hard to follow -- please try to lay it out clearly -- but it's looks like you are not calculating the t-statistic correctly. Please check your formulas again.

Comment: @Glen_b can you tell me where I am calculating the t stat wrong?

Comment: The denominator looks wrong, but please make your working clearer first. In particular, you should explain what formulas you're using at each step, and *why you're doing that*. Don't just throw formulas at numbers, or you'll end up doing something twice you should do only once, as it seems you did here. Failure to show your working and justify your steps is likely to be part of your difficulty.

Comment: Incidentally, it isn't a t-statistic (at least not by my lights) -- it doesn't have a t-distribution. You could argue it's a [studentized statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentization).